# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x20 in tid 2327

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a problem in debugging code in android using xamarin forms application crash in master detail and give me this error 
I tried to clean , build and delete bin and obj no solution works

I use xamarin.forms 4.0
vs 2019 16.1.1

```
=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Adddress Reporting
=================================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x7d689fd678):0x7d689fd668  00 1c 40 b9 c0 03 5f d6 fd 7b bf a9 fd 03 00 91  ..@..._..{......
0x7d689fd678  08 20 40 b9 a8 00 c8 37 88 01 e0 37 00 00 40 f9  . @....7...7..@.
0x7d689fd688  fd 7b c1 a8 c0 03 5f d6 60 08 00 b0 01 0a 00 f0  .{...._.`.......
0x7d689fd698  03 0a 00 f0 00 24 06 91 21 80 08 91 63 8c 0a 91  .....$..!...c...

No native Android stacktrace (see debuggerd output).

===============================================06-01 15:23:19.407 E/mono-rt ( 2327): /proc/self/maps:

==================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
=================================================================06-01 15:23:19.407 E/mono-rt ( 2327): 12c00000-52c00000 rw-p 00000000 00:01 18226                              /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (region space) (deleted)

06-01 15:23:19.407 E/mono-rt ( 2327): 6fdee000-70096000 rw-p 00000000 103:09 28170                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot.art
06-01 15:23:19.407 E/mono-rt ( 2327): 70096000-7019c000 rw-p 00000000 103:09 28174                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-core-libart.art
06-01 15:23:19.407 E/mono-rt ( 2327): 7019c000-701e6000 rw-p 00000000 103:09 28176                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-conscrypt.art
06-01 15:23:19.407 E/mono-rt ( 2327): 701e6000-7021c000 rw-p 00000000 103:09 28177                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-okhttp.art
06-01 15:23:19.407 E/mono-rt ( 2327): 7021c000-70220000 rw-p 00000000 103:09 28180                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-legacy-test.art
06-01 15:23:19.407 E/mono-rt ( 2327): 70220000-70263000 rw-p 00000000 103:09 28182                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-bouncycastle.art
06-01 15:23:19.407 E/mono-rt ( 2327): 70263000-7029e000 rw-p 00000000 103:09 28201                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-ext.art
06-01 15:23:19.407 E/mono-rt ( 2327): 7029e000-70a8b000 rw-p 00000000 103:09 28204                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-framework.art
06-01 15:23:19.407 E/mono-rt ( 2327): 70a8b000-70b17000 rw-p 00000000 103:09 28316                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-telephony-common.art
06-01 15:23:19.407 E/mono-rt ( 2327): 70b17000-70b20000 rw-p 00000000 103:09 28329                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-voip-common.art
06-01 15:23:19.407 E/mono-rt ( 2327): 70b20000-70b29000 rw-p 00000000 103:09 28350                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-ims-common.art
06-01 15:23:19.407 E/mono-rt ( 2327): 70b29000-70b4d000 rw-p 00000000 103:09 28406                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-apache-xml.art
06-01 15:23:19.407 E/mono-rt ( 2327): 70b4d000-70b75000 rw-p 00000000 103:09 28409                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-org.apache.http.legacy.boot.art
06-01 15:23:19.407 E/mono-rt ( 2327): 70b75000-70b76000 rw-p 00000000 103:09 28414                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-android.hidl.base-V1.0-java.art
06-01 15:23:19.407 E/mono-rt ( 2327): 70b76000-70b79000 rw-p 00000000 103:09 28424                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-android.hidl.manager-V1.0-java.art
06-01 15:23:19.407 E/mono-rt ( 2327): 70b79000-70c04000 rw-p 00000000 103:09 28425                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-hwEmui.art
06-01 15:23:19.407 E/mono-rt ( 2327): 70c04000-70c2b000 rw-p 00000000 103:09 28432                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-hwTelephony-common.art
06-01 15:23:19.407 E/mono-rt ( 2327): 70c2b000-70c64000 rw-p 00000000 103:09 28494                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-hwframework.art
06-01 15:23:19.407 E/mono-rt ( 2327): 70c64000-70c66000 rw-p 00000000 103:09 28500                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-org.simalliance.openmobileapi.art
06-01 15:23:19.408 E/mono-rt ( 2327): 70c66000-70c67000 rw-p 00000000 103:09 28502                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-org.ifaa.android.manager.art
06-01 15:23:19.408 E/mono-rt ( 2327): 70c67000-70c6d000 rw-p 00000000 103:09 28506                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-hwaps.art
06-01 15:23:19.408 E/mono-rt ( 2327): 70c6d000-70c73000 rw-p 00000000 103:09 28511                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-hwcustEmui.art
06-01 15:23:19.408 E/mono-rt ( 2327): 70c73000-70c78000 rw-p 00000000 103:09 28513                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-hwcustframework.art
06-01 15:23:19.408 E/mono-rt ( 2327): 70c78000-70c7f000 rw-p 00000000 103:09 28524                             /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot-hwcustTelephony-common.art
06-01 15:23:19.409 F/libc    ( 2327): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x20 in tid 2327 (nyname.Ministry)
```

Any solution for this error ?

Answer (score 0):

kamal The crash information you provided is not enough for a diagnosis. As you can see, it reads, "No native Android stacktrace (see debuggerd output)."

Could you please share some code, of what you were trying to do?
It could be an issue with improper asynchronous programming. To figure out where exactly the app is crashing, you could:

1. Create a System Catchpoint exception,
2. Launch a profiler to track the error,
3. (and should) Use try-catch statements, to basically figure out exactly what line the code is crashing on, & what's the internal stack trace.

Comment: I did that but it crashing in master detail only in vs 2019 but in vs 2017 works fine . that's mean the problem isn't in the code

Comment: Use Xamarin Profile or the other ways to start an android log, you will get more error details than just the one in your application output. Are you also using the same Emulator? It could be an error in Visual Studio that you can report

Comment: I'm not using an emulator and it's an vs issue they should update xamarin.android sdk